# How to create a bootstrap card the same height as container with scrollable body

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As the title states, I am trying to create a bootstrap card that will be the same height as its container, I want the card header at the top, the footer at the bottom and then I want the body to fill the remaining space. I would like the body to be scrollable so that it can be full of content but will not change the height.

FYI this is for a chat window.

I created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/MikeG42/Ldo1njy3/
Make sure you are viewing the results at the bottom as the columns need to be next to each other.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 red">
         Some Content here that sets determines the height
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-header">Header (this card should be same height as red)</div>
            <div class="card-body scrollable">
               This area Should be scrollable and fill the remaining height of its parent container.<br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">Footer (should be aligned with bottom of red)</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.red
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 350px;
}

.scrollable
{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with simple jquery code like this

```
$('.card').height($('.red').height()).removeClass('h-100');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5f9xe2y/

Comment: Thank you this works great, I would just like to add that it should go in a window resize event so that it will keep the correct height when the window changes size.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to turn your second column into a **flex container** with a `flex-direction: column`.

Then, the card should have `height: 0;` and `flex-grow: 1;`.
This way, it's height won't depend on it's content but on the height of the first column.

**Beware that it won't work if the left column is shorter than the height of the header plus footer of the second column.**

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.red
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 350px;
}

.scrollable
{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.card-full-height {
  height: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 red">
      Some Content here that sets determines the height
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="card card-full-height">
        <div class="card-header">Header (this card should be same height as red)</div>
        <div class="card-body scrollable">
          This area Should be scrollable and fill the remaining height of its parent container.<br><br>

          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">Footer (should be aligned with bottom of red)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```